# Sending variables to embedded Ruby/ Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I wanted to make a function to return someone's age from a rails database.

```
function getName(name_input) {
return <%= Names.find_by(name: name_input).age %>
}
```

When I've tried similary functions is seems that rails doesn't have access to local variables. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

`getName` is a Javascript function that gets called on the client side. Code in `<%=%>` is executed at the server **before** sending the HTML view to the client; at that moment, Rails has no idea what `name_input` is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `<%= Names.find_by_name(name_input).age %>`

Answer (score 0):

<% %> are erb tags which embed Ruby inside HTML that your rails server will render and send to the client as pure HTML.

You cannot mix server-side ruby with client-side javascript.